# Libraries missing for ruby-2.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, pry

I am trying to recompile my ruby because pry stopped working.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Sorry, you can't use Pry without Readline or a compatible library.
```

I did

```
brew update
rvm get head
rvm cleanup all
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.4
```

But I'm still getting errors during the installation and can not get pry working.

```
Libraries missing for ruby-2.2.4: /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/libruby.2.2.0.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
```

and

```
Error running '__rvm_patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f -i /Users/kel/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.4/openssl3.patch',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/kel/.rvm/log/1479717703_ruby-2.2.4/patch.apply.openssl3.log
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More info about your system would be helpful. It looks like OS X. Which version is it?

Comment: osx version 10.12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3332) might help you.

```
brew rm openssl
brew cleanup openssl
brew install openssl
```