# Libraries missing for ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

currently trying to install Ruby 2.3.1 using rvm on my terminal(macOS Sierra) but ran into this error

> Libraries missing for ruby-2.3.1:
>   /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib,/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries

This error is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715966/libraries-missing-for-ruby-2-2-4) on stack overflow but the solution there did not work for me.
I am new to Ruby, so any help would be much appreciated.

This is the full output from the terminal by the way.

```
ruby-2.3.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.3.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.3.1 - #configure
ruby-2.3.1 - #download
ruby-2.3.1 - #validate archive
ruby-2.3.1 - #extract
ruby-2.3.1 - #validate binary
Libraries missing for ruby-2.3.1: /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib,/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 10, trying to compile.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sabrina.zuraimi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.1 - #downloading ruby-2.3.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.1 - #extracting ruby-2.3.1 to /Users/sabrina.zuraimi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.1....
ruby-2.3.1 - #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.3.1 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.1 - #compiling...........
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/sabrina.zuraimi/.rvm/log/1481003831_ruby-2.3.1/make.log
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
compiling ./missing/explicit_bzero.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling dmyenc.c
linking miniruby
config.status: creating ruby-runner.c
generating encdb.h
encdb.h updated
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
making srcs under enc
/bin/sh: /Applications/Xcode-beta: No such file or directory
make: *** [srcs-enc] Error 127
++ return 2
```

Comment: not exactly an answer, but when i used rbenv instead of rvm, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do you have Xcode installed? If not, you can just get the command line tools here: http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

It seems like the message is saying that you had Xcode-beta but removed it and now it has no way to install properly. The command line tools should be good enough

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error but the installation completes successfully.

```
Napuka:~ joaquin$ rvm install ruby-2.3.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/joaquin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.3 - #downloading ruby-2.3.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.7M  100 13.7M    0     0  2219k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 2220k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.3.3 - #extracting ruby-2.3.3 to /Users/joaquin/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.3....
ruby-2.3.3 - #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.3.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.3 - #compiling........................................................-
ruby-2.3.3 - #installing.........
ruby-2.3.3 - #making binaries executable..
Installed rubygems 2.5.2 is newer than 2.4.8 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.
ruby-2.3.3 - #gemset created /Users/joaquin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
ruby-2.3.3 - #importing gemset /Users/joaquin/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems.........|
ruby-2.3.3 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.3.3 - #gemset created /Users/joaquin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
ruby-2.3.3 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/joaquin/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.3.3 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.3.3 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.3.3 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

But your message looks quite explicit:
    /bin/sh: /Applications/Xcode-beta: No such file or directory
Do you have that directory?

Comment: Turns out I did not have the C-compiler that is needed as they could not find where I put my Xcode beta(installed a new Xcode beta and deleted the previous one so my Xcode beta was actually in /Applications/Xcode-beta2